# Jekyll/Liquid: Use a for loop with custom tags in a table template

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to populate the following table output using Jekyll and Liquid (please note that the variables in for loops are arbitrary):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        {% for row in headerrows %}
            <tr>
                {% for cell in headercells %}
                    <td>{{content}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
                {% for cell in cells %}
                    <td>{{content}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What would be the best approach to do this? If I use a custom plugin with custom tags, would it be possible to parse something like:

```
{% table %}

    {% row %}

        {% header %}
        Header cell 1
        {% endheader %}

        {% header %}
        Header cell 2   
        {% endheader %}

        {% header %}
        Header cell 3
        {% endheader %}

    {% endrow %}

    {% row %}

        {% cell %}
        Cell 1 content.
        {% endcell %}

        {% cell %}
        Cell 2 content.
        {% endcell %}

        {% cell %}
        Cell 3 content.
        {% endcell %}

    {% endrow %}

{% endtable %}
```

...into arrays that would then be processed within for loops in the template?